# How can Data wish to be human if he is emotionless?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In *Star Trek: TNG*, how can Data wish to be human if he is emotionless? How could he wish for something (anything) since that would involve desire, which is an emotion?

Comment: When did Data say he wanted to be emotionless?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I've edited to reflect what OP seems to mean

Comment: @Valorum: I did wonder if that was it.

Comment: Data said that since he is manufactured in the form of human, his maker would have wanted him to emulate human. Hence in getting close to being human, he is actually fulfilling his objective of being. This is a perfectly logical decision, not the emotional one.